# mysql. sort on temporary column based

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables called **albums** and **photos** with **ratings** being one of the attribute in the photos table.

I want to know whether it is possible to **sort** albums based on a **total number of photos in an album**. The total number of photos should be generated based on a **condition** on the **ratings** attribute.

I dont want to add a new column to the albums table having the photos counts based on rating as the ratings keep changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating new column, you can achieve the same by using inner query (will act like temp table)

Like...

```
SELECT * FROM album a
JOIN ( SELECT yourlogic(rating) AS total_no_photos,  album_id FROM photo
      WHERE yourlogic  
      GROUP BY album_id 
       ) temp_photo
ON temp_photo.album_id = a.album_id
ORDER BY total_no_photos
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The total number of photos in an album should be fetched in a subquery.
2. Give a meaningful alias to it say photos_count
3. You can use the photos_count in order by clause. The result will be sorted.